# Number of k-permutations, but with constraints forbidding certain combinations

Tags: combinatorics

The number of k-permutations, that is, the number of ordered sequences of length $k$
from a set of $n$ elements, is $n^\underline{k}$.

Is there a way to calculate the number of k-permutations, given additional constraints that forbid certain elements from appearing in the sequence? For example, for $n=5$ and elements $n_1, \dots, n_5$, calculate the number of 3-permutations excluding permutations containing both $n_4$ and $n_5$.

Comment: Do you wish to exclude both $n_4$ and $n_5$?  If so, then you are asking for the number of $3$-permutations of $\{n_1, n_2, n_3\}$, which is just $3!$.

Comment: In the example, I would like to exclude sequences containing _both_ $n_4$ and $n_5$. So, $\{n_1,n_2,n_4\}$ would be valid, while e.g. $\{n_1,n_4,n_5\}$ would not be.

Comment: The approach will vary depending on the situation. In your example, subtracting the number of forbidden sequences is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1:**  Find the number of $3$-permutations of $S = \{n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5\}$ excluding those permutations that contain both $n_4$ and $n_5$.

**Method 1:**  We will count directly.

If neither $n_4$ nor $n_5$ is in the $3$-permutation, then $n_1, n_2, n_3$ must be in the permutation.  There are $3!$ ways to permute those three elements.

If exactly one of $n_4$ or $n_5$ is in the $3$-permutation, there are two ways to select which of the elements $n_4, n_5$ will appear in the $3$-permutation, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select which of the other two elements will appear in the $3$-permutation, and $3!$ ways to arrange the selected elements.  Hence, there are $$\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}3!$$ $3$-permutations containing exactly one of $n_4$ or $n_5$.

In total, there are
$$3! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}3!$$
$3$-permutations of the set $S$ which do not contain both $n_4$ and $n_5$.

**Method 2:**  We will use complementary counting.

We subtract the number of $3$-permutations of $S$ containing both $n_4$ and $n_5$ from the total number of $3$-permutations.

If there are no restrictions, there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select the three elements that will appear in the permutation and $3!$ ways to arrange those elements.  Hence, there are $\binom{5}{3}3! = 5^{\underline{3}}$ possible $3$-permutations.

Of these, there are $\binom{3}{1}3!$ that contain both $n_4$ and $n_5$ since there are three ways to select the remaining element that will appear in the $3$-permutation and $3!$ ways to select the remaining elements.

Hence, there are
$$\binom{5}{3}3! - \binom{3}{1}3!$$
$3$-permutations of the set $S$ which do not contain both $n_4$ and $n_5$.

**Example 2:** Find the number of $4$-permutations of the set $S = \{n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5\}$ except those containing $n_2$ and $n_3$ or those containing $n_4$ and $n_5$.

There are
$$5^{\underline{4}} = \binom{5}{4}4!$$
permutations of the elements since we must select four of the five elements in set $S$ and then arrange them.

From these, we will subtract those $4$-permutations which contain both $n_2$ and $n_3$ or both $n_4$ and $n_5$.

$4$-*permutations containing both $n_2$ and $n_3$*:  If a $4$-permutation contains both $n_2$ and $n_3$, then it must contain two of the other three elements in set $S$.  They can be selected in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.  The four selected elements can be arranged in $4!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{3}{2}4!$$
such permutations.

$4$-*permutations containing both $n_4$ and $n_5$*:  By symmetry, there are
$$\binom{3}{2}4!$$
such permutations.

However, if we subtract these two amounts from the total, we will have subtracted the $4$-permutations that include $n_2$ and $n_3$ and $n_4$ and $n_5$ twice, once when we designated them as containing $n_2$ and $n_3$ and once when we designated them as containing $n_4$ and $n_5$.  We only want to subtract them once.  Therefore, we must add them to the total.

$4$-*permutations containing both $n_2$ and $n_3$ and both $n_4$ and $n_5$*:  These permutations must contain the four elements $n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5$.  Thus, there are $4!$ such permutations.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of $4$-permutations of $S$ that do not contain both $n_2$ and $n_3$ or both $n_4$ and $n_5$ is
$$\binom{5}{4}4! - 2\binom{3}{2}4! + 4!$$

The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle can be used in generalizations of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves the example, but I have problems generalizing it. Assume, for example, 4-permutations from the same set of 5 elements with forbidden combinations containing either $n_2$ and $n_3$ or $n_4$ and $n_5$. Then similar to method 2 with
$$\binom{5}{4}4!-\binom{3}{2}4! -\binom{3}{2}4!$$
subtracting all permutations containing either of the forbidden pairs, we would make a mistake by subtracting permutations containing $n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5$ twice. Any ideas to generalize the approach?

Comment: I added a solution to your second example, which uses the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.